# how to hide keyboard on text view to return in swift3

Tags: ios, swift

In My project, the introduction tells us that when the return key is pressed, the keyboard for UITextView will disappear. But actually the return key can only act as '\n'.is there any solution?

Comment: Please explain more and show your code this is not useful